# A java.lang.NullPointerException exception has occurred

Tags: netbeans

[image]
A java.lang.NullPointerException exception has occurred.
However, the system should continue working without further problems.
When I create a class, I get this error.
Can you help me fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the IDE?

Comment: looks like a problem with your IDE / JDK version. Try to upgrade both